# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python, pygame

this doubt is from pygame and space invaders game

checking of boundaries of player

```py
playerX += playerX_change    
if playerX <=0:
    playerX = 0
elif playerX >=736:
    playerX = 736
```

checking of boundaries of enemy & enemy movement

```py
enemyX += enemyX_change           
if enemyX <= 0:
    enemyX_change = 0.3
elif enemy >= 736:
    enemyX_change = -0.3
```

Comment: What's `playerX`?

Comment: Please show the complete error trace. It is very likely that a function and a variable have the same name.

Comment: Just a guess: 4th line: `enemyX >= 736`? enemy`might be a function...

Answer (score 1):

`enemy` seems to be a function. You have to use the variable `enemyX` insread of the function `enemy`:

<s>`elif enemy >= 736:`</s>

```py
elif enemyX >= 736:
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of enemyx you have put enemy in checking boundaries

Comment: It's the other way around.